# Set properties to script groovy component in apache camel

Tags: java, apache, groovy, apache-camel

I'm invoking groovy scripts from apache camel. When I'm invoking the groovy script, I'm getting below error saying `No such property: INPUTS for class: Script1`. 
How can I overcome this? I tried setProperty(). setHeader but no luck.

```
from("activemq:queue:test.ChooseIManger")
     .script().groovy("resource:classpath:tests/port/test.gsh")
```

Error :

```
2017-10-02 13:42:00 DEBUG ScriptBuilder:413 - Script evaluation failed: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: INPUTS for class: Script1
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: INPUTS for class: Script1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.script.ScriptBuilder.runScript(ScriptBuilder.java:469)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.script.ScriptBuilder.doEvaluateScript(ScriptBuilder.java:428)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.script.ScriptBuilder.evaluateScript(ScriptBuilder.java:409)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.script.ScriptBuilder.evaluate(ScriptBuilder.java:160)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.script.ScriptBuilder.evaluate(ScriptBuilder.java:164)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ScriptProcessor.process(ScriptProcessor.java:47)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:79)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: INPUTS for class: Script1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:155)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: INPUTS for class: Script1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317)
    ... 17 more
```

I tried to setProperties as below but I'm getting the same error

```
from("activemq:queue:test.ChooseIManger").setProperty("INPUTS",constant("123")).script().groovy("resource:classpath:tests/port/test.gsh");
```

I know that I can do this as below. But I want to do this with apache camel groovy component.

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setProperty("INPUTS", inputs);
binding.setProperty("RESULT", results);

GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding); 
Object script = shell.evaluate(getScript("tests/port/test.gsh"));
```

**test.gsh**

```
def inputVal = INPUTS['param']

RESULT.outputVal = inputVal + 'output';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are some pre-defined bindings: context, properties, ...

http://camel.apache.org/scripting-languages.html

in your case to access property should be like this (camel 2.9+):

```
property.resolve("INPUTS")
```

Comment: Thank you daggett for the answer. But how to set this to the java DSL while using the existing groovy resources?

Comment: do you mean you have scripts like `def inputVal = INPUTS['param']` and you don't want to change them? if yes then you need to implement custom Processor. http://camel.apache.org/processor.html

Comment: One small clarification daggett. Are u referring to create a custom processor to set property or invoke groovy scripts or both?

Comment: both. you can put all available properties as binding and call script. also you can cache compiled script - so you will not loose time for recompile.